# Set z-index of leaflet popup

Tags: leaflet, popup

I'd like to have my Leaflet popup (tooltip) such that it appears outside the bounding div of the map, rather than it being hidden once it hits the map border.

I see `zindex()` as a tile layer method.

What about for tips/popups?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible using the standard popup in Leaflet. The reason for this is that the map is located a `div` element with the CSS-property set to `overflow: hidden`. The Leaflet popup is another `div` element within the map `div`. Broken down to the HTML of your map, your question becomes equivalent to [this one on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521387/show-child-div-within-hidden-parent-div).

You could make a clone of the leaflet-popup-pane `div` and insert it somewhere outside of your map, but then you would need to make all the synchronisation manually, which is probably not what you want to get into.

A more feasible approach would probably be to place your popup information completely outside the map, something like in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mt6rhpqr/). A click on the marker displays the popup information in the `div`.

Comment: Your approach is good. However, I think Leaflet should have done like OpenLayers for pop-up, meaning that if the popup is going to be outside of viewport by top, when open, you just open it at the bottom of the feature, and so on. That would fix this kind of "issue".

Comment: > I think Leaflet should have done [...]<
I cannot but firmly agree. This is a total nonsense by leaflet. It makes it impossible to create maps with a (example) heading positioned on the map, without actually destroying all pop ups since then overlayed all by the heading too. :shrug: 

Probably it is the reason why things have a price when they are actually useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. Just get the popup pane by it's classname and set the style:

```
            function setPopUpZIndex() {
            let paneCol = document.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-popup-pane')
            let paneToChange = paneCol[0];
            console.log(paneToChange);
            paneToChange.style.zIndex = 3000;
            }
```

Comment: Yeah, it is possible to add the number. Does it have any effect, whatsoever? No. The z-index of the pop up is defined by its parent element `.leaflet-pane` element which seems hardest to 400. But even if you would change that to -1, the pop ups would not actually respect any other z-index than their parent index. And this, is the biggest ever mess-up of leaflet. It effectively means, that any text positioned inside the map will either be invisible, or overlay the pop ups. You cannot thus position any text between map, and pop up.